# Find a matrix such that $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let
$$W = span\left\{ {\left( {\matrix{
   1  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   0  \cr 
   1  \cr 
 } } \right),\left( {\matrix{
   0  \cr 
   2  \cr 
   1  \cr 
   { - 1}  \cr 
 } } \right)} \right\}$$

I was asked to find a matrix, $A$ which satisify the following:
$$W = \left\{ {x \in {\mathbb{R}^4}|Ax = 0} \right\}$$

$A$ must be $n\times 4$. $W$ is actually $null(A)$, so every linear combination of the vectors is a solution for $Ax = 0$.

Other then those observations, I am not sure how to find $A$.
Looking for guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Think orthogonal.

Comment: Not familiar with this term :(

Comment: The rows of A must be orthogonal (dot product is zero) to the two vectors in W.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to proceed if instead of the given kernel the range instead is given. For example : $T:V_3 \rightarrow V_3$ such that the equation of $R(T)$ is $4x_1-3x_2+x_3 = 0$. Should I post a new question for this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one method.  You know that $(w,x,y,z)^T \in \ker(A)$ iff
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
w\\x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix} = 
s \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\2 \\ 1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} s \\ 2t \\ t \\ s-t \end{pmatrix}
$$
for some $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$.  There are two free variables and two linear relations:
\begin{array}{cccccc}
w & & - y & - z &=& 0\\
& x & -2y & & = &0 & \, .
\end{array}
Using these coefficients as the rows of our matrix, we find that
$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1 & -1\\
0 & 1 & -2 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
satisfies the criteria.

Comment: I wanted to get a matrix like this but forgot to realize that both my rows were identical...Not so smart.

Comment: Right, the kernel of your matrix contained $W$, but was one dimension too big!

Comment: Sorry but can't follow how did get the system of equations, can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @LilianHernández $z = s-t$ and $x = 2t$. Plug in $s = w$ and $t = y$ and you get the system of equations above.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\;A=(a_{ij})\;$, then we want

$$\underline x\in W\iff \underline0=A\underline x=\begin{pmatrix}\sum_{j=1}^4a_{1j}x_j\\{}\ldots\\\sum_{j=1}^4a_{4j}x_j\end{pmatrix}$$

But the above means

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 a_{ij}x_k=0\;,\;\;\forall\,j=1,2,3,4\iff r_i\perp\underline x\;\;\;\forall\,i=1,2,3,4$$

with $\;r_i=$ the i-th row of $\;A\;$, and thus

$$\forall\,i=1,2,3,4\;,\;\;r_i\perp\underline X\;,\;\;\forall\,\underline x\in W\iff r_i\perp \alpha_k\;,\;\;$$

where $\;\{\alpha_k\}\;$ is *any* basis of $\;W\;$ , and since the two given vectors are clearly a basis of $\;W\;$ (why?), you can form your matrix's rows with elements from $\;W^\perp\;$ . Note that

$$W^\perp:=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{pmatrix}\in\Bbb R^4\;:\;\begin{cases}x+w=0\\2y+z-w=0\end{cases}\;\right\}$$

and , of course, $\;\dim W=2\iff \dim W^\perp=2\;$