# Finding a matrix such that $W=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^4 |Ax=0 \right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $W\subset\mathbb R^4 $ such that $W= \operatorname{sp} \left\{ 
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0 \\ 0 \\1 \end{pmatrix} ,
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2 \\ 1 \\0 \end{pmatrix},
> \begin{pmatrix} 1\\  -2 \\ -1 \\2 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$
>
> Find a matrix $A\in M_{n\times 4} (\mathbb R)$ such that: $W=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^4 |Ax=0  \right\}$ ($n$ doesn't matter)

I made a matrix of the above span, and got it to RREF: $\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0& 0& 1 \\ 0& 1& 2& -2 \\ 0& 0& 0& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ So the basis is the first two vectors but I don't get how to find a such matrix as were asked.

I think this is the kernel as I understand, so the kernel should be the basis maybe ?

Comment: You are correct that it is the kernel. Note that your computation of RREF shows that $W$ is 2-dimensional. If you write out precisely what it means for those vectors to be in the kernel, you'll realize that the rows of $A$ must consist of row vectors in the orthogonal complement to $W$.

Comment: If for $x \in W$, $Ax = 0$, then $Ab = 0$ for every $b$ in that set that generates $W$.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802998/find-a-matrix-such-that-ax-0/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need are $x,y,z,w$ such that 
$$x+0y+0z+w=0$$
$$x+2y+1z+0w=0$$
$$x-2y-1z+2w=0$$

you have reduced the system to 
$$x+w=0$$
$$y+2z-2w=0$$

So $x=-w$ and $y=2w-2z$
Setting $z=0, w=1$ and $z=1, w=0$ we get
$$(-1,2,0,1)$$ and $$(0,-2,1,0)$$

So let $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1&2&0&1\\
0&-2&1&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $W \subseteq \ker A$

Since the rows of $A$ are independent the rank of $A$ is $2$ and so since $A:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ the dimension of the kernel is $2$ and so
$W =\ker A$.

Comment: What you did here is find the kernel of $Ax$, using the basis of $W$ ?

Comment: I think it is the other way around I found $A$ having a given kernel.

Answer (score 2):

Since the vectors $w_1$ and $w_2$ of $W=span\{w_1,w_2,w_3\}$ are linearly independent, we can find two vectors $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to create a basis in $\mathbb{R}^4$, $W' =\{w_1,w_2,\alpha,\beta\}$.

We construct a matrix in this basis that will send $W$ to zero: $$A_{W'} = \left( \begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$$

The $W'$ here indicates that this is a matrix represented in the $W'$ basis. Now we need to change back to the standard basis: $B = \{ (1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1) \}$ and we can use a change of basis matrix for this: $$Q = \left( w_1, w_2, \alpha, \beta \right)$$ here $Q$ is written in column form.

Finally you can calculate the matrix $A$ you wish to find by $$A = Q A_{W'} Q^{-1}.$$

This matrix sends any linear combination of $w_1$ and $w_2$ to zero. This means that it sends $w_3$ to zero as well.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is the matrix with you are looking for. Suppose that $Ae_1=e_1$. Next we have three condition:

1)$A(e_1+e_4)=0$, so $Ae^4=-e_1$, because $Ae_1=e_1$

2)$A(e_1+2e_2+e_3)=0$, so $A(2e_2+e_3)=-e_1$

3)$A(e_1-2e_2-e_3+2e_4)=0$

In 3 by $Ae_1=e_1$ and $Ae_4=-e_1$ we have $A(-2e_2-e_3)=e_1$, so if we put for example $Ae_2=e_2$ and $Ae_3=-e_1-2e_2$ the matrix $A$ satisfies your conditions and we have:

$Ae_1=e_1$

$Ae_2=e_2$

$Ae_3=-e_1-2e_2$

$Ae_4=-e_1$

So in standard basis:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 && 0 && -1 && -1 \\ 0 && 1 && -2 && 0\\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 0 && 0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The OP is asking for a matrix where $Ker(A) = W$. Here the kernel has dimension three, whereas $W$ has dimension 2.

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the mistake.

Comment: Is there a name for the operation you did here ? Also, why can you suppose that $Ae_1=e_1$ ?

Comment: No, I suppose that $Ae_1=e_1$, because I can, because $e_1 \not\in W$ to get the simpliest equations. Generally you always can suppose $Av=w$ when $v,w \not\in W$