# Finding a linear transformation L where Ker(L) is spanned by a specific set

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the linear transformation $L:R^3->R^3$ where $Ker(L)$ is spanned by ${(1,2,0), (2,0,0)}$

What I got is $L(u_1 u_2 u_3)=(2u_1-u_2, 0, 0)$ 
Is this correct? I just tried stuff

Is there any methodology to solve such problems?

Comment: There is an infinite number of such transformations, so asking for “the” transformation isn’t really right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is not correct, since $(2,0,0)$ is not in the kernel.

Notice that $\text{span}\left\{(1,2,0),(2,0,0) \right\}=\text{span}\left\{e_1,e_2 \right\}$, so an example of such a linear transformation is simply the projection onto the third coordinate $L:\mathbf{R}^3\to\mathbf{R}^3,(x,y,z)\mapsto (0,0,z).$

Comment: is there any general method to do it

Comment: In this case, you can solve it by inspection. For a general method, take a look here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802998/find-a-matrix-such-that-ax-0.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\text{span}\left\{(1,2,0),(2,0,0) \right\}=\text{span}\left\{e_1,e_2 \right\}$

We can define the general map

$e_1 \mapsto 0$

$e_2 \mapsto 0$

$e_3 \mapsto v$

where $v \in \mathbb R^3$ is an arbitrary non-zero vector

This gives

$ L(c_1e_1 + c_2e_2 + c_3e_3) $

$= c_1L(e_1) + c_2L(e_2) + c_3 L(e_3)$

$= c_3v$

So the linear transformations are exactly those that scale some fixed arbitrary non-zero vector by $c_3$

[The answer by rae306 corresponds to $v = (0,0,1)$]