# Characterising linear transformations based on the null space

Tags: linear-algebra

Characterise all linear transformations, $T:ℝ^4→ℝ^3$, whose null is spanned by $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(0,1,1,1)$.

The general direction is to find a matrix of the transformation with respect to the standard basis and some basis $B$ in $ℝ^3$.

Thanks,

Comment: That is already a nice characterisation. I don't understand what this is asking for.

Comment: I already gave a complete answer to this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/752036/find-linear-transformation-given-kernel/752062#752062

Comment: Say $u,v$ your two vectors, and let $w,t\in\mathbb{R}^4$ such that $\{u,v,w,t\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$. Then all the linear transformations you are looking for are linear extension of: $u\mapsto0, v\mapsto 0, w\mapsto x, t\mapsto y$, for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $\{x,y\}$ is linearly independent set.